# Python class, Attribute error although the attribute is present

Tags: python-3.x, class

In my code although there is an the attribute 'melee_strengths' I am getting this error. I have already re-indented this and tried this without the '_' between 'melee' and 'strengths' but still got this error. I also replaced melee_strengths with xyz to see if it was an error with my typing and still got the error. I don't know how to solve this problem. Could you help please?

```
class Enemy(Character):
     def __int__(self,char_name,char_desc):
         super().__int__(char_name,char_desc)
         self.hit_points = 0
         self.melee_strengths = {
             'Normal damage': None,
             'Piercing damage': None,
             'Bludgoning damage': None}
         self.special_strengths = {
             'Acid damage': None,
             'Cold damage': None,
             'Heat damage': None,
             'Holy damage': None,
             'Undead damage': None}
     def set_melee_strength(self, norm_str, pierce_str, bludge_str):
         self.melee_strengths['Normal damage'] = norm_str
         self.melee_strengths['Piercing damage'] = pierce_str
         self.melee_strengths['Bludgoning damage'] = bludge_str
```

Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Object oriented programing/Week2/my_rooms.py", line 34, in <module>
    dave.set_melee_strength('neutral', 'resistant', 'weak')
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Object oriented programing/Week2\character.py", line 52, in set_melee_strength
    self.melee_strengths['Normal damage'] = norm_str
AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'melee_strengths'
```

Edit:
The code in which I'm using Enemy class is:

```
dave = Enemy("Dave","A smelly zombie")
dave.describe()
dave.set_conversation('Be prepared to face my wrath')
dave.set_hit_points(50)
dave.set_melee_strength('neutral', 'resistant', 'weak')
dave.set_special_strength('neutral','neutral','neutral','weak','resistant')
dave.get_melee_strengths()
dave.get_special_strengths()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the snippets where you're invoking this code? What is `dave` and how was it initialized?

Comment: Are you initializing the Enemy class? That means are you typing `Enemy(args)` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Typo in your init function name. The init function should be `__init__` not `__int__.`

Comment: Thank you I was being an idiot and not seeing that small error. I was just focused on the lower bits that I couldn't see it.